# Cygwin application crashes (memory problems)

Tags: memory-leaks, cygwin, msys2

I have a network and multithreaded application that was originally developed for Linux. It uses libev, mbedtls, protobuf-c and other libraries.
My goal is to run it on Windows. I tried to port it with msys2 and cygwin.
I decided to do it with cygwin, because seems there were more packages in the repository.
Finally, I started it on Windows, but it works extremely unstable.
In gdb it almost always crashes with damaged stack. After recovering SP the backtrace usually shows:

```
Thread 1 "App" received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x0000000100b86619 in operator new (sz=0) at /usr/src/debug/gcc-9.3.0-2/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/new_op.cc:50
50      /usr/src/debug/gcc-9.3.0-2/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/new_op.cc: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000100b86619 in operator new (sz=0) at /usr/src/debug/gcc-9.3.0-2/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/new_op.cc:50
#1  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb) set $pc = *(void **)$rsp
(gdb) set $rsp = $rsp + 8
(gdb) info stack
#0  0x00007ff85c4e415f in WaitForSingleObjectEx () from /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/KERNELBASE.dll
#1  0x000000018013efde in sig_send (p=<optimized out>, p@entry=0x0, si=..., tls=<optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/sigproc.cc:719
#2  0x00000001801656d4 in pthread_kill (thread=<optimized out>, sig=6) at /usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/thread.cc:3314
#3  0x000000018013b61b in raise (sig=<optimized out>) at /usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/signal.cc:306
#4  0x000000018013b94f in abort () at /usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/signal.cc:402
#5  0x0000000180176905 in dlmalloc (bytes=bytes@entry=32) at /usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/malloc.cc:4587
#6  0x00000001800d4369 in malloc (size=32) at /usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.4-1/winsup/cygwin/malloc_wrapper.cc:56
#7  0x00000001801367ab in _sigfe () at sigfe.s:35
#8  0x0000000100b86619 in operator new (sz=32) at /usr/src/debug/gcc-9.3.0-2/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/new_op.cc:50
#9  0x00000001008bd229 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>::allocate (this=<optimized out>, __n=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/src/debug/gcc-9.3.0-2/x86_64-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/ext/new_allocator.h:102
#10 std::string::_Rep::_S_create (__capacity=__capacity@entry=7, __old_capacity=__old_capacity@entry=0, __alloc=...)
    at /usr/src/debug/gcc-9.3.0-2/x86_64-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.tcc:1058
#11 0x00000001008bc97b in std::string::_S_construct<char*> (__beg=0x100c40ae5 "0.0.0.0", __end=<optimized out>, __a=...)
    at /usr/src/debug/gcc-9.3.0-2/x86_64-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_iterator_base_funcs.h:138
#12 0x00000001008be8d7 in std::string::_S_construct_aux<char const*> (__a=..., __end=<optimized out>, __beg=0x100c40ae5 "0.0.0.0")
    at /usr/src/debug/gcc-9.3.0-2/x86_64-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h:5137
#13 std::string::_S_construct<char const*> (__a=..., __end=<optimized out>, __beg=0x100c40ae5 "0.0.0.0")
    at /usr/src/debug/gcc-9.3.0-2/x86_64-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h:5140
#14 std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string (this=0xffffc548, __s=0x100c40ae5 "0.0.0.0", __a=...)
    at /usr/src/debug/gcc-9.3.0-2/x86_64-pc-cygwin/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.tcc:665
. . .
#21 0x00000003f50310f2 in ev_invoke_pending () from /usr/bin/cygev-4.dll
#22 0x00000003f5033f95 in ev_run () from /usr/bin/cygev-4.dll
#23 0x00000001005c4471 in ev::loop_ref::run (this=0x100be7a28 <app+8>, flags=0) at /usr/include/ev++.h:211
```

Sometimes it crashes in malloc(). Obviously it has memory corruption.
I have some questions:

- are there any memory tools in cygwin? (sanitizer etc)
- is it real to get a stable application on cygwin?
- does it make sense to use mingw/msys2 instead of cygwin?

UPD: Tested it on msys2 with the same results. So I think there's not much difference between cygwin and msys2. The problem is with the code, not the environments.

Comment: as there are thousands of application ported on Cygwin, I will bet on a application error, probably due to wrong assumption about the system on which is run. But of course it is possible a subtle error on the Cygwin "kernel". Most of the system calls are build around BSD like source

Comment: "are there any memory tools in cygwin?" Yes, you can use Valgrind on Cygwin for example.  "is it real to get a stable application on cygwin?" yes, I have non-trivial software that runs stable on Cygwin.  "does it make sense to use mingw/msys2 instead of cygwin?" mingw and msys2 are very different things--msys2 could work as well as (or as poorly as Cygwin) but it depends on your application.  The libraries you're trying to use are very non-trivial and might take additional effort to port to Cygwin. But if you can provide *minimal* example code that reproduces the problem I could take a look.

Comment: Thanks, Iguananaut, but I just can't provide such example of code, at least now ... About Valgrind - I couldn't find it for cygwin. I still have a problem with the app crash. I updated backtrace above, it crashes usually in new() operator.

Answer (score 0):

I've also encountered a `SIGABRT` crash on Cygwin when performing `malloc`. The software under test is GNU nano version 5.4. However, it only crashes when it has NOT been run with `gdb`, so I added `fprintf` everywhere trying to pinpoint the place it crashes. To my surprise, it seems that an `abort` was called inside of `malloc`, which I've never met before. Here are the steps to reproduce it:

- Get the code: `git clone --depth 1 --branch v5.4 git://git.savannah.gnu.org/nano.git`
- Build the app:

  - Install the dependencies, including `libncurses5-dev`: https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/nano.git/tree/README.hacking
  - `./autogen.sh; ./configure; make`
- Prepare the rcfile: `echo "set indicator" > test.nanorc`
- Run the app: `./nano.exe --rcfile=test.nanorc`
- After that, click on the upper right "Full Screen" button
- Observe that the app crashes
- An alternative way (which is how I tested it) is to run inside of `tmux`:

  - Run the app
  - Split window horizontally
  - Close the newly created panel
  - Press an enter to the app

[image: full screen]
[image: nano crashed]

My tracing is that it crashes at `malloc`, from `nmalloc` (utils.c:295), from `add_undo` (text.c:968), from `do_enter` (text.c:898), from `process_a_keystroke` (nano.c:1653). After some googling, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181241/sigabrt-in-malloc-c-what-just-happened) said that it's likely to be a heap corruption somewhere else, so maybe a memory checking tool is needed (eg. Valgrind, but unfortunately [it doesn't seem to be supported on Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811356/memory-leak-tool-on-cygwin)).

Comment: This should be reported to Nano.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I don't think so, because Cygwin is **not** listed in the [official supported platforms](https://www.nano-editor.org/download.php).

Comment: I'm not seeing a list of supported platforms there. It's normal to not ship binaries for all supported platforms.